# osx _curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminfo database

Tags: python, macos, ncurses, curses, terminfo

I'm using python curses and developing under PyCharm. but whatever a simple curses program, it always gives me such an exception. what i had tried were:

- add export `TERM="xterm-256color"` and export `TERMINFO="/usr/share/terminfo"`, but there was still appeared such exception:`_curses.error: setupterm: could not find terminfo database`(useless)
- add such TERM environment variable into PyCharm run configuration like this way,but still ran failed, here is configuration screen capture:
  [image: run configuration]

Comment: When you run: `infocmp xterm` in a terminal, what is the output?

Comment: xterm|xterm terminal emulator (X Window System),
 am, bce, km, mc5i, mir, msgr, npc, xenl,
 colors#8, cols#80, it#8, lines#24, pairs#64,
 acsc=``aaffggiijjkkllmmnnooppqqrrssttuuvvwwxxyyzz{{||}}~~,
 bel=^G, blink=\E[5m, bold=\E[1m, cbt=\E[Z, civis=\E[?25l,
 clear=\E[H\E[2J, cnorm=\E[?12l\E[?25h, cr=^M,
 csr=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dr, cub=\E[%p1%dD, cub1=^H,
 cud=\E[%p1%dB, cud1=^J, cuf=\E[%p1%dC, cuf1=\E[C,
 cup=\E[%i%p1%d;%p2%dH, cuu=\E[%p1%dA, cuu1=\E[A,

Comment: Try changing the TERM in PyCharm to be `xterm-color` or `xterm`. If that doesn't work, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: changed both and still not work.

Comment: There's only a few possibilities: (a) the environment `TERMINFO` isn't used by the application, (b) there's a non-Apple ncurses being used which isn't configured for the case-insensitive filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Complete "Hail Mary pass" from my site as I don't code in Python nor use OSX, but recently I've run into (maybe) similar problem when I linked my program against source compiled ncurses. Most probably due my fault during compilation, ncurses did not look for terminal database in "standard" locations. I've discovered this using `strace` on problematic binary.

A quick and dirty workaround for my problem was (assuming TERM=xterm-256color) to create separate terminfo database in my home directory and link system database into it:

```
mkdir ~/.terminfo
ln -s /lib/terminfo/x ~/.terminfo
```

Comment: no... the question is about OSX, which has the file, and both its system library and add-ons such as MacPorts would have that description (OSX doesn't have `strace`).